# Wrong saving in data file

Tags: c++

I am watching a youtube video from 2020 on how to make login system with c++. I have the exact same code as him but I have 1 error where when I save my first password everything works fine the password and user are saved as ID:1, but when I add another user the ID is set to -858993459.
Here's the code, it's only in main.cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

class loginManager {
public:
    loginManager() {
        accessGranted = false;
   }
   void login() {
        cout << "Enter your UserName and Password.\n";
        cout << "UserName: ";
        cin >> userNameAttempt;
        int usrID = retriveFile(userNameAttempt, "users.dat");
        if (usrID != 0) {
            cout << "Password: ";
            cin >> passwordAttempt;
            int pswID = retriveFile(passwordAttempt, "passwords.dat");
            if (usrID == pswID) {
                cout << "Successfull login!\n";
                accessGranted = true;
                login();
            }
            else {
                cout << "Wrong password!\nTry Again!\n\n";
                login();
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Wrong username!\nTry Again!\n\n";
            login();
        }
    }
    void addUser(const string username, const string password) {
        if (retriveFile(username, "users.dat") != 0) {
            cout << "That username is already in use!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        int id = 1 + getLastID();
        saveFile(username, "users.dat", id);
        saveFile(password, "passwords.dat", id);
    }
    int getLastID() {
        fstream file;
        file.open("users.dat", ios::in);
        file.seekg(0, ios::end);
        if (file.tellg() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        string s;
        for (int i = -1; s.find("#") == string::npos; i--) {
            file.seekg(i, ios::end);
            file >> s;
        }
        file.close();
        s.erase(0, 5);
        int id;
        istringstream(s) >> id;
        return id;
    }
    int retriveFile(string attempt, const char* pathFile) {
        string line;
        fstream file;
        string currentChar;
        long long eChar;

        file.open(pathFile, ios::in);
        while(1) {
            file >> currentChar;
            if (currentChar.find("#ID:") != string::npos) {
                if (attempt == line) {
                    file.close();
                    currentChar.erase(0,4);
                    int id;
                    istringstream(currentChar) >> id;
                    return id;
                }
                else {
                    line.erase(line.begin(), line.end());
                }

            }
            else {
                istringstream(currentChar) >> eChar;
                line += (char)decrypt(eChar);
                currentChar = "";
            }
            if (file.peek() == EOF) {
                file.close();
                return 0;
            }
        }   
    }
    void saveFile(string p_line, const char* pathFile, const int& id) {
        fstream file;
        file.open(pathFile, ios::app);
        file.seekg(0, ios::end);
        if (file.tellg() != 0) {
            file << "\n";
        }
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        for (int i = 0; i < p_line.length(); i++) {
            file << encrypt(p_line[i]);
            file << "\n";
        }
        file << "#ID:" << id;
        file.close();
    }

    long long encrypt(int p_letter) {
        return powf(p_letter, 7) * 3 - 70;
    }
    long long decrypt(long long p_letter) {
        return powf((p_letter + 70) / 3, 1/7.f);
    }
private:
        string userNameAttempt;
        string passwordAttempt;
        bool accessGranted;
};


int main() {
    loginManager app;
    app.addUser("Something", "Somethingelse");
    app.login();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `-858993459` is a close to Microsoft debugging code. Uninitialized stack memory. You probably want to debug getLastID(). Maybe `s` is empty

Comment: You probably want a `ulong` instead of `long`.  Also, if this is for learning purposes then it isn't a big deal, but you should be using a standard encryption method instead of what is defined here (which is arguably not even encryption). Better yet, you could hash the passwords, which is what most authentication systems do anyways.

Comment: So is the tutorial old or should I change something also I think the error is in getLastID()

Comment: warning C4717: 'loginManager::login': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow

Comment: The problem with Internet tutorials is no one curates them. Unless you already *almost* know how to do the job, or have a good quack detector, it's hard to tell if a tutorial really is any good.

Comment: if the files do not exist this code goes into an infinite loop, I expected it to create a new file for me

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact content of the input files. It should also specify the exact output and the desired output of the program.

Comment: -858993459 = 0xcccccccc, which means you've read uninitialized memory. See [When and why will a compiler initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Comment: `getLastID()` says `s.erase(0, 5); int id; istringstream(s) >> id;` but to get out of the loop `s` had to be `#ID:1` so the erase makes `s` empty and then the extraction to `id` fails because there is no integer in the stream.  And that's why `id` has an uninitialized value.  I think the erase is meant to only erase the `#ID:` part so it should be `s.erase(0, 4); int id; istringstream(s) >> id;`